# Best way to pass state to asynchronous functions in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js application with asynchronous code like this:

```
var localvar1 = ...;
var localvar2 = ...;
var localvar3 = ...;
// do async database query
conn.query("select ...", function(err, res) {
    // fetch results asynchronously 
    res.fetchAll(function(err, rows) {
        if (rows.length == 0)   // no, data, fetch from external HTTP source
        {
            // fetch from Internet asynchronously 
            https.get(..., function() {
                // ok, got it, now save
                // I need values from original function here ***
                saveData(localvar1, localvar2, localvar3);
            });
        }
    });
);
```

What is the best way to pass values of localvar1-3 to innermost function?

If you suggest some library for this, please provide example code that would work with the code I wrote above.

Comment: `// fetch from Internet asynchronously` part could be a function acepting your `localvar`s (and something else, if needed).

Comment: @elmigranto: how? please show code.

Comment: Your variables are already visible in the innermost function, need more details on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: BTW, what's are `localvar`s are keeping? Can they be changed in different part of code before `// fetch from Internet asynchronously` fires?

Comment: localvar1 and 2 are "res" and "req" from Express app.get(). localvar3 is a local variable containing some user data. None of them are changed before fetch fires, however a different user requesting some URL via Express would invoke this same function with his local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to closures, inner functions have access to local variables defined in outer functions or in the module itself, so your code as written will work *if* `localvar1`, et.al., don't get changed while waiting for your `https.get()` callback to be called. If they do get changed, your callback will see their new values, not the values they had at the time of the request. If that's a problem, create a new closure to "trap" them:

```
https.get(..., (function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    return function() {
        saveData(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
})(localvar1, localvar2, localvar3));
```